# Find all $y \in \mathbb R$ for which g is continuous in point $y$

Tags: real-analysis

> $g:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, $g(x)= \begin{cases} \sin(x) & x \in \mathbb Q\\ 0 & x \notin \mathbb Q \end{cases}$.
>  Find all $y \in \mathbb R$ for which function $g$ is continuous at point $y$.

It is my idea but I'm not sure if it's correct so please check:

- For $y \in \mathbb Q$:
  $g(y)=\sin(y)$
   $\lim_{x \to y}g(x)=0$
  So I have $\sin(y)=0$ so $y=k\pi$ for $k \in \mathbb Z$ but $y \in \mathbb Q$ so it is contradiction
- For $y \notin \mathbb Q$:
  $g(y)=0$
   $\lim_{x \to y}g(x)=\sin(y)$
  So I have $\sin(y)=0$ so $y=k\pi$ for $k \in \mathbb Z$ and $y \notin \mathbb Q$ so it is truth

Final answer: $y=k\pi$ for $k \in \mathbb Z$

Comment: I agree with your conclusion but I think the arguments are flawed. In particular $\lim_{x \to y} g(x)$ doesn't exist if $y$ is not a multiple of $\pi$. 

I don't think you should break it up into the cases $y \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $y \not\in \mathbb{Q}$. Instead try $y=k\pi$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $y \neq k\pi$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.